# PPPoE connection between vm and host

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, pppoe

I have a windows 10 host and an Ubuntu vm which is running a pppoe-server. May I know if it is possible or not to use dial-up from windows 10 to connect to the Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, as long as the host and the VM are, in fact, connected using virtual Ethernet.

This means "NAT mode" or "user networking" mode is *not* suitable – you need e.g. "Host-only network (vboxnet)" in VirtualBox or "tap" in Qemu/KVM. These act like regular Ethernet links and can carry any kind of frame including PPPoE.

(VirtualBox's "bridged" networking may also work, but it's a bit complex under the hood – a virtual tap/vboxnet interface is simpler.)

Comment: I am using vmware workstation and have set network adapter to "host-only" for my Ubuntu, but Windows 10 give me error 651 when using dial-up connection to Ubuntu